# elasticsearch date range accuracy

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

**TL;DR:** Using a range filter on a date with a `lte` condition never returns the record for that date.

In the following code segements, focus on the `@timestamp` field.

**Query:**

```
POST logstash-*/logs/_search
  {
    "filter": {
      "range": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "gte": null,
          "lte": "2015-08-31T15:00:07.397Z",
          "format" : "date_time"
        }
      }
    },
    "size": 20,
    "from": 1,
    "sort": [
      {
        "@timestamp": {
          "order": "desc"
        }
      }
    ],
    "fields": [
      "*",
      "@timestamp"
    ]
 }
```

**Query result:**

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 586,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "logstash-2015.08.31",
            "_type": "logs",
            "_id": "AU-ERb3Ndl1LVbEg-Dnb",
            "_score": null,
        "fields": {
           "@timestamp": [
              "2015-08-31T15:00:06.455Z"
           ]
        },
        "sort": [
           1441033206455
        ]
     }, (more hits...)
```

**Next step:**

I take the `@timestamp` value from the first result (`"2015-08-31T15:00:06.455Z"`) and put it in the same query, under the `lte` key.

**Augmented query:**

```
POST logstash-*/logs/_search
  {
    "filter": {
      "range": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "gte": null,
          "lte": "2015-08-31T15:00:06.455Z",
          "format" : "date_time"
        }
      }
    },
    "size": 20,
    "from": 1,
    "sort": [
      {
        "@timestamp": {
          "order": "desc"
        }
      }
    ],
    "fields": [
      "*",
      "@timestamp"
    ]
 }
```

**Augmented query result:**

```
{
       "took": 6,
       "timed_out": false,
       "_shards": {
          "total": 5,
          "successful": 5,
          "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 585,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "logstash-2015.08.31",
            "_type": "logs",
            "_id": "AU-ERbH6dl1LVbEg-Dna",
            "_score": null,
            "fields": {
               "@timestamp": [
                  "2015-08-31T15:00:03.871Z"
               ]
            },
            "sort": [
               1441033203871
            ]
         }, (more hits...)
```

As you can see above, the record for date by which I queried does not appear in the result list. The hit count has decremented by 1, and the first result is for an earlier time and not the exact time which equals the one I queried for.

**Index template in use:**

```
PUT _template/my_template
{
  "template" : "logstash-*",
  "mappings" : {
      "logs" : {
        "_source" : {"enabled" : "true"},
        "properties" : {
          "@timestamp" : { "type" : "date", "format" : "date_time" },
          # more fields here
        }
      }
  }
}
```

I'm using elasticsearch 1.7.1.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set the value of `"from"` to `1` in your search request. What this means is that neglect the first result and show rest of the results. Hence you find the first result missing. If you set `"from"` to `0` or remove it completely, you'll get the desired results.

Comment: Doh! Can't believe I missed that.